# Why are the Geonim the only group of scholars with a positive name?

Tags: geonim

The other groups, Tannaim, Amoraim, Savoraim, Rishonim, Achronim, all have names that are neutral.  Only the Geonim are called a positive thing, "geniuses."  Is this because they were somehow greater than the other groups, does anyone comment on this.

Comment: "Gaonim" means "deans" because they were the deans of the schools in Babylon. Pretty neutral sounding to me. Like how "Tanna" means "teacher".

Comment: I think the term gaon became a compliment after the period of Gaonim.